# Fetching Initial State in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building an application where I need to fetch the initial redux sate from the server before my main component mounts.
In my actions, I used redux-thunk to get the necessary data:

```
export const getInitialStateSuccess = (state: any): IfetchThemeSuccess => {
    console.log('state', state);
    return {
        type: FETCH_INIT_STATE,
        state
    };
};


// here I fetch the data from the server and call getInitialStateSuccess
// to pass it to redux init state
export const getInitialState = () => {
     return (dispatch: any) => {
         api.getInitState().then((data) => {
              dispatch(getInitialStateSuccess(data));
          });
      };
 }
```

However, I do not know where I should call getInitialState(). I need to initialize the state of the app before the main component mounts. Do you think it would be a good practice to call this action in componentWillMount? It has to be called only once. 
Please let me know if the approach I'm describing above is a good practice or not.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it in `WillMount` but `DidMount` is preferred. This is because `WillMount` can be called twice if you have server-side rendering.

Either way, you're going to need a intermediary "loading" screen before hand since the call is asynchronous, and it is going to render before data has loaded.

Comment: Do you think if it is a good practice if I provide an empty intial state to redux initially createStore(reducer, []) and then in componentWillMount I'll call getInitialState()?

Comment: That's fine, it's all on how you handle the business logic. Personally, I would have some initial state that reflects that stuff isn't loaded. Eg. `{loaded: false, fetching: false, listOfItems: []}` and work from there.

Comment: Yes, loaded flag is a great idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best place to place your API or server calls is in the componentDidMount() lifecycle.

Note that this will trigger a re-render once your data overrides your initial state.

This will force you to manage your initial state before the componentDidMount() lifecycle. It is common practice to do this in the constructor method.

You can see this for yourself in the React documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

"componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering."

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is very helpful. A follow up question is, do I ever need to use componentWillMount for fetching any data? Or it is only used for some configurations of the app not related to data

Comment: Technically you could use componentWillMount for fetching data, but the major disadvantage being that, as Nick said in another comment, if you are doing any server side rendering your component will be rendered twice. Once on the server side and once on the client side. So componentDidMount() is superior in the sense that it will always only re-render once on the client side once the state is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial state will live in a reducer. And on your react component, once you make it `connect`ed, you can use the helper method `mapStateToProps` to access the current state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my main question is where I should fetch this initial state from the server?

Comment: hey @João : where/how would it go in a reducer? would you make the API call there?